# jquery detect if input area is not empty while user is typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small jquery code which hide/show an icon when an input field is empty/have something
My code is:

```
$("#pass1").on("change",function(){
  if($("#pass1").val())
      $("#showpass").show();
  else
  $("#showpass").hide();

});
```

But this occures only when user finish typing and moves to next field or removes focus but I want to do this while user is typing i.e it should occur as soon as user either enters or delete an single character.How can I do this ?

Comment: use `onInput` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/). Try this:

```
$('#pass1').keyup(function() {
    //your code goes here
});
```